# Add border list <li> element on 2 columns of <li> element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to create to 2 columns using `li` and need to add border to each of `li`,but there are double border for 2 `li`, this is what I tried:

```css
.ul1 {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 0px;
}

.li1 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="ul1">
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
    </ul>
```

And based on what I had tried, I can use `child` selector to solve this:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hafizihamid/09qvdLfa/15/)

**HTML FIle**

```
    <ul class="ul1">
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
      <li class="li1">Test</li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS File**

```
.ul1 {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0px;
}

.li1 {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  margin-right: -1px;
  &:nth-child(5) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  }
    &:nth-child(10) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  }
}
```

but Im not sure if that one is good practice or not, or there are could be better way,I could use some guidance and suggestions on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fix list then you can try using `:nth-child(-n+5)` which will select first five child of your list where you can control `border`.

Check the below snippet.

```css
.ul1 {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0px;
}

.li1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.li1:nth-child(-n+5) {
  border-right: 0px;
}

.ul1 li:last-child,
.ul1 li:nth-child(5) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1">
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how about double border at border-top and border-bottom ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below css

```
   .ul1 {
      column-count: 2;
      column-gap: 0px;
    }

    .li1 {
      border-top: 1px solid blue;
      border-left: 1px solid blue;
      border-right: 1px solid blue;
      margin-right: -1px;
     list-style: none;
    }

    .ul1 li:last-child, .ul1 li:nth-child(5) {
 border-bottom: 1px solid blue; 
margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I try to Add border list `<li>` element on 2 columns of `<li>` Element 
that will be shown below :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul{
  width:760px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}
li{
  line-height:1.5em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
#double li  { width:50%;} <span class="code-comment">/* 2 col */</span>
#triple li  { width:33.333%; } <span class="code-comment">/* 3 col */</span>
#quad li    { width:25%; } <span class="code-comment">/* 4 col */</span>
#six li     { width:16.666%; } <span class="code-comment">/* 6 col */</span>
</style>
<title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="double"> <span class="code-comment"><!-- Alter ID accordingly --></span>
  <li>CSS</li>
  <li>XHTML</li>
  <li>Semantics</li>
  <li>Accessibility</li>
  <li>Usability</li>
  <li>Web Standards</li>
  <li>PHP</li>
  <li>Typography</li>
  <li>Grids</li>
  <li>CSS3</li>
  <li>HTML5</li>
  <li>UI</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And The Output of Above Codes Is show in blow Image :

[Output Image Is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orLfP.png)

I think that code is useful to you.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below

```css
.ul1 {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0px;
    margin:0;
     border-right: 1px solid blue;
     border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
     padding:0;
         
}

.li1 {

  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1">
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
  <li class="li1">Test</li>
</ul>
```

example it will work